# Compute the value of the sum $7\cdot 11+11\cdot 15+15\cdot 19+\cdots+95\cdot 99$

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

Solution: My attempt:
=$9^2-2^2 +13^2-2^2+17^2-2^2...97^2-2^2$
=$(9^2+13^2+17^2...97^2)-2^2( 23 )$
Focus on the first part. 81+169+289+441...Here first-order differences are 88, 120, 152... and the second-order difference is common to be 32. Therefore the series is of the form of $p(n)^2+q(n)+r$. If we plug n=0, we get the first term, if plug n=1, we get the second term, if we plug n=2, we get the third term and so on. 
$p*0^2+q*0+r=81$
r=81
$p*1^2*q*1+81=169$
$p+q+81=169$
$p+q=88…(1)$
$p*2^2+q*2+81=289$
$4p+2q=208…(2)$
Solving (1) and (2), we get p =16,  q =72, and  r =81.

Therefore the general term formula is $16n^2+72n+81$. Now, if we start adding them up, 81 will be there 23 times. Then there will be 72, 144, 216 etc, 22 times. This sum will be 72(1+2+3+...22) =18216. At the last 16n^2 will be there 22 times. This sum will be $16(1^2+2^2+3^2...22^2) = 16 ((22) (23) (45)/6) = 60720$. Grand total is $1863+18216+60720-92= 80707$.

Comment: $15\cdot 19=17^2-2^2$

Comment: The sequence $\{9,13,17,21,\ldots\}$ is arithmetic with common difference $4$, so the $n$-th term is $a_n=4n+5$. Then the sum you want to evaluate is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{23}(4n+5-2)(4n+5+2)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{23}(16n^2+40n+21)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have one more way to do it easily. As we can see the sequence has the general term $T_n$=$(4n+3)(4n+7)$ and the sum of sequence will be equal to $\sum {T_n} $ from $n=1$ to $n=23$. Now, the sum will appear as :
$$16\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+20n(n+1)+21n$$ where putting n=23 will give $80707$

It will be easier as there will be less chance for error as there will be less steps than what you have approached the question. Also what fellow users have given, **it is just the same but easier coefficients to apply for**.

Comment: Thanks. How do you reach the general term? With induction?

Comment: I used these points-(1)all are odd (2)all have the difference 4 (3)2nd part in the multiplication is also differing by 4 (4) So it must be (4k+r)(4k+q) and then put the value of 1,2,.(this doesn't mean putting all the values) to get r and 1 and then checked it through other numbers. I have used these steps in many questions (never fails me).

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{n=0}^{n=22} (4n+7)(4n+11)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{n=22} 16n^2+72n+\color{red}{77}\\
&= 80707
\end{align}